# Python argsparse Namespace in Class definition

Tags: python, oop, namespaces, argparse

I'm having trouble understanding how can I extract args with argparse.Namespace

let's say I have a class:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

and later I'm calling it:

```
config = {"foo": "bar", "y": "xyz"}

x = SomeClass()
x.args = argparse.Namespace(**config)
```

How do I extract this config dict inside SomeClass?
I want to use it in some class method

Comment: `self.args.foo`…?

Answer (score -1):

You can use vars:

```
   x.args = vars(argparse.Namespace(**config))
```

Comment: So, just `x.args = config` then?